# subsetting using another variable

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data frame that contains a column called `country` and I want to subset the table based on that. I tried the following:

This will return me the full table:

```
> country  = 'hk' 
> dt[dt$country == country]
```

This will return me the correct subset:

```
> dt[dt$country == 'hk']
```

Why is it so? Does that mean I can't subset a data frame based on another variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are incorrect if the OP is subsetting the `rows` of a `data.frame`, the correct option would be `row, column` indexing.  If we don't put `,`, by default it will be taken as the column index.  If needed, `drop=FALSE` can also be used where there is only a single column.

```
 dt[dt$country == country,, drop=FALSE]
```

If it is a `data.table` object

```
setkey(dt, country)[country]
#  country
#1:      hk
```

Or

```
dt[country == get("country", envir = parent.frame())]
#    country
#1:      hk
```

#### data

```
dt <- data.table(country = c('hh', 'hk', 'hh', 'kn'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: `dt[dt$country == country,]` still gives me the wrong answer. Any solution?

Comment: @hans-t May be you need `drop=FALSE`.  How about showing a small reproducible example with `?dput`

Comment: oops sorry, the previous answer is correct for data.frame. Could you also give an answer for data.table please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put comma `,` in the second command, then it will give you correct answer, with all rows having country as `hk`

```
    > country  = 'hk' 
    > dt[dt$country == country,]
```

Also, in the below command too, you have to put comma `,`

```
    > dt[dt$country == 'hk',]
```

Comment: I am slow in typing may be. Sorry. Go ahead!! Not on purpose.

Comment: Sorry, then, I misunderstood you.  Have a great day!

Comment: No need of sorry. As its a simple question you might get answer quickly in no time and many people are there, so it happens. No one's fault. Till the time I post, the answers are already given.